# How to download a certain byte of the file via http

Tags: java, http

How to download first 125 bytes and 125 last byte file via HTTP protocol ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you want to send an appropriate `Range` header. See the [HTTP/1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.1) for more information. Be aware that not all servers will support this, mind you. You *may* need to transfer the whole file, just to get to the last 125 bytes. Of course, you can get just the first 125 bytes by *requesing* the whole thing, and then only *reading* the first 125 bytes before killing the connection.

In theory I believe you should be able to use:

```
Range: 0-124,-125
```

Note that this will give interesting results if the full response would be less than 250 bytes...

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Range: bytes=-255
```

Answer (score 2):

send [content-range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) in request headers for specific range of content as response. but for which the webserver has to support range requests