# Lazy access to InputStream by offering InputStream getter

Tags: java, io, inputstream

An API that I'm implementing deals with InputStreams containing hierarchically structured data i.e. nested blocks, including a number of images in the leaf blocks. (If you must know, it is [CBEFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBEFF) data that I'm parsing.) Each block of data is prefixed with a header containing some meta-data about that block.

```
1st level 1 header
    1st level 2 header
    1st level 2 data block
    2nd level 2 header
    2nd level 2 data block
2nd level 1 header
    3rd level 2 header
    3rd level 2 data block
```

The original InputStream is an argument to the constructor of my API classes and is passed around down the hierarchy.
Currently I'm reading the images into byte arrays in the constructor of my API classes, so each constructor blocks while reading the complete data that that class is responsible for and later on when clients call the relevant getter method of that API class they will get the image data served from memory. I'd much rather offer the contained images in the form of some kind of lazy InputStreams to clients of my API, so that the image bytes are only read from the original InputStream as a result of clients reading bytes of the resulting InputStream delivered by the getter. This makes it possible, for example, to do progressive rendering, which is useful as the original InputStream is slow.

Is there an elegant way to solve this with InputStreams?

Comment: Err, just remove all your image-reading code?

Comment: @EJP, yes that would work if there was only one image and the image data was the last element in the InputStream. I have multiple images, and the header of image _n_+1 is following the data of image _n_. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputStream` isn't suitable for random access. So reading parts of it isn't going to work in most cases, even though you can achieve similar effects on *some* input streams using a combination of [`reset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29) and [`skip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29). But not all streams support `reset`, and skipping bytes is often as expensive as reading bytes.

So I suggest you try some alternate approach. Either you buffer the whole stream to some random-access buffer, like a temporary file, which still means reading all the bytes off the stream in the first place. Or you find a way to get random access to the original source. You didn't specify what kind of source you're dealing with, but e.g. for a HTTP connection you can [download parts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5978052/1468366) using a [range request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35). Similar solutions might work for other sources.

No matter how you implement the random access (and seeing your comment, you'll likely do so using an `InputStream` with `reset` and `skip`), you can create your own class to represent a part of that stream. You can let that class itself be an instance of `InputStream` by subclassing [`FilterInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html).

```
cLass SubStream extends FilterInputStream {
    private long offset;
    public SubStream(long offset, InputStream parent) {
        super(parent);
        this.offset = offset;
    }
    public SubStream(InputStream parent) {
        this(0, parent);
    }
    @Override public void reset() throws IOException {
        in.reset();
        in.skip(offset);
    }
    public SubStream subStream(long offset) {
        return new FilterInputStream(this.offset + offset, in);
    }
    public Object syncObject() {
        return in;
    }
}
```

You'd have to ensure that any operation using one of these streams calls `reset` first. If you need to enforce a proper end-of-stream treatment, you'll have to override most `read` implementations. If concurrent access might be possible, then you'll want to synchronize operations on the underlying stream. So the code using this class could look something like this:

```
     synchronized(part.syncObject()) {
         part.reset();
         return read(part);
     }
```

Comment: The source is a smart card in a smart card reader (so, very slow connection, we're talking only several kbps here, hence the need to support progressive rendering). Mark & reset are supported and skipping is cheap.